# Is there a way to check if the defective unit is, Processor/Motherboard?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, desktop

My computer doesn't turn on when pressing the power button so I checked each component to distinguish where the problem is.

I removed all the components and test one by one, starting from the power supply. I test the power supply by connecting green and black wires. The fan of power supply spins so it concludes me that it is working.

Next is the motherboard with CPU attached. I plugged in the 24-pin and 8-pin ATX of power supply to motherboard. I turned it on by connecting power pins on the motherboard using a screw driver (it was taught by our technical instructor when I was in school). The fan of PSU doesn't work but it powers the LED on the motherboard, indicating that it receives power, which concludes me that either motherboard or cpu is defective.

**Is there a way that I can test if the sole problem is motherboard or processor? I don't have spare so I can't test individual component.**

Comment: is this a new build? is this a LGA or PGA socket? Are there any beeping sounds or error lights (There's more than one).

Comment: "I test the power supply by connecting green and black wires. The fan of power supply spins so it concludes me that it is working."  That's not nearly enough troubleshooting to surmise that it's working. Just because it turns on doesn't mean it's delivering the right power to the various wires.  Really you need known-good spare parts; if you want to play computer repair, they're necessary.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek its an old one. My old unit's power supply gave up. It has a burning smell so I bought a new one. There are no speakers installed on the board so I can't hear anything. Besides, since it doesn't light my board, I think it wouldn't produce beep sounds.

Answer (score 1):

Just because the fans and LEDs power on does not mean that the power supply is good.  Fans and LEDs use up very little amperage, and the rest of the system may not be getting enough power to fully boot up.  If you search on Google, (or other search engine), you can find a power supply tester that you can use to see if it's really working or not, (search for: "power supply tester").  If the tester shows that the power supply is good, then you'd have to test the CPU and motherboard with different units to see if they're bad or not.  There's no real way to test a CPU and motherboard individually without another one to test with; in other words, you can't test if a motherboard is bad without another motherboard.  CPUs and motherboards change too much for them to have dedicated testers on the market, bit of a shame too.